# Anagram tester in C

Tags: c, anagram

I am trying to implement an anagram tester in C. When calling the program, the user enters two words in double quotes, like  "listen" and "silent". 
I have almost got it to work, but I am having some trouble with a helper function I wrote to get rid of spaces in the two input words. Here is the code for this function:

```
void noSpaces(char word[100]) {
    /*
    This is a function to get rid of spaces in a word
    It does this by scanning for a space and shifting the
    array elements at indices > where the space is
    down by 1 as long as there is still a space
    there. 
    */
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        while (word[i] == ' ') {
            for (int j = i; j < 100; j++) {
                word[j] = word[j+1];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, it works fine when I pass the input word from the `main` function to this helper. The problem is the second call to this function. When I call this function on the second input, if `k` is the number of spaces in the first input, then the function erases the first `k` letters of the second input. For example, typing `./anagram " banana" "banana"` will give me a false negative, and if I add a print statement to see what's going on with the inputs after `noSpaces`
is called on them, I get the following:

```
banana
anana
```

Here is the code for the full program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    //this if statement checks for empty entry
    if (isEmpty(argv[1]) == 0 || isEmpty(argv[2]) == 0) {
        //puts("one of these strings is empty");
        return 1;
    }
    //call to noSpaces to eliminate spaces in each word
    noSpaces(argv[1]);
    noSpaces(argv[2]);
    //call to sortWords
    sortWords(argv[1]);
    sortWords(argv[2]);
    int result = compare(argv[1], argv[2]);
    /*
    if (result == 1) {
        puts("Not anagrams");
    } else {
        puts("Anagrams");
    }
    */
    return result;
}

int compare(char word1[100], char word2[100]) {
    /*
    This is a function that accepts two sorted 
    char arrays (see 'sortWords' below) and
    returns 1 if it finds a different character
    at entry i in either array, or 0 if at no 
    index the arrays have a different character.
    */
    int counter = 0;
    while (word1[counter] != '\0' && word2[counter] != '\0') {
        if (word1[counter] != word2[counter]) {
            //printf("not anagrams\n");
            return 1;
        }
        counter++;
    }
    // printf("anagrams\n");
    return 0;
}

void sortWords(char word[100]) {
    /*
    This is a function to sort the input char arrays
    it's a simple bubble sort on the array elements.
    'sortWords' function accepts a char array and returns void,
    sorting the entries in alphabetical order
    being careful about ignoring the 'special character'
    '\0'.
    */
    for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
        int i = 0;
        while (word[i + 1] != '\0') {
            if (word[i] > word[i + 1]) {
                char dummy = word[i + 1];
                word[i + 1] = word[i];
                word[i] = dummy;
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
}

void noSpaces(char word[100]) {
    /*
    This is a function to get rid of spaces in a word
    It does this by scanning for a space and shifting the
    array elements at indices > where the space is
    down by 1 as long as there is still a space there. 
    */
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        while (word[i] == ' ') {
            for (int j = i; j < 100; j++) {
                word[j] = word[j + 1];
            }
        }
    }
}

int isEmpty(char word[100]) {
    // if a word consists of the empty character, it's empty
    //otherwise, it isn't
    if (word[0] == '\0') {
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

I know there is a library that can deal with strings, but I really
would like to avoid having to use it. I've come this far already without needing it, and I feel the problem is mostly solved but for one small thing I don't see.

I come from a java background, and I'm new to C, if that explains whatever error I made.

Comment: When `j` is 99, you access `word[j+1]`, that is, `word[100]`. But there is no `word[100]` because `word` only has 100 entries.

Comment: Why double quotes? Is this an assignment?

Comment: @David Schwartz thanks for catching that, didn’t realize. However, if a word is well under 100 characters, does this explain the weird effect I’m seeing?

Comment: @n.m yes it is, I decided to use command line arguments instead of scanf because I thought there might be issues getting the second part of this assignment to work. I will just tell the TA to put double quotes around their inputs, in case they have entries with spaces. When I first wrote this I didn’t think I had to treat this case.

Comment: @P.Gillich There's no way to know. The effect of accesses out of bounds can be unpredictable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, strings are arrays of `char` with a null terminator, ie a byte with the value `0` usually represented as `'\0'`. You should not assume any particular length such as `100`. Indeed the array size in the function prototype arguments is ignored by the compiler. You can determine the length by scanning for the null terminator, which is what `strlen()` does efficiently, or you can write the code in such a way as to avoid multiple scans, stopping at the null terminator. You should make sure your functions work for the empty string, which is an array with a single null byte. Here are the problems in your code:

In function `noSpaces`, you iterate beyond the end of the string, modifying memory potentially belonging to the next string. The program has undefined behavior.

You should stop at the end of the string. Also use 2 index variables to perform in linear time:

```
void noSpaces(char word[]) {
    /*
    This is a function to get rid of spaces in a word
    It does this by scanning for a space and shifting the
    array elements at indices > where the space is
    down by 1 as long as there is still a space
    there. 
    */
    int i, j;
    for (i = j = 0; word[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (word[i] != ' ') {
            word[j++] = word[i];
        }
    }
    word[j] = '\0';
}
```

You can simplify `compare` to use a third as many tests on average:

```
int compare(const char word1[], const char word2[]) {
    /*
    This is a function that accepts two sorted 
    char arrays (see 'sortWords' below) and
    returns 1 if it finds a different character
    at entry i in either array, or 0 if at no 
    index the arrays have a different character.
    */
    for (int i = 0; word1[i] == word2[i]; i++) {
        if (word1[i]) == '\0')
            //printf("anagrams\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    // printf("not anagrams\n");
    return 1;
}
```

`sortWords` has undefined behavior for the empty string because you read the `char` at index `1`, beyond the end of the array. Here is a corrected version:

```
void sortWords(char word[]) {
    /*
    This is a function to sort the input char arrays
    it's a simple bubble sort on the array elements.
    'sortWords' function accepts a char array and returns void,
    sorting the entries in alphabetical order
    being careful about ignoring the 'special character'
    '\0'.
    */
    for (int j = 0; word[j] != '\0'; j++) {
        for (int i = 1; i < j; i++) {
            if (word[i - 1] > word[i]) {
                char dummy = word[i - 1];
                word[i - 1] = word[i];
                word[i] = dummy;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You should declare functions before use, or alternately define them before use. Your code compiles because the compiler accepts old style C where the prototype for yet unseen functions was inferred from the arguments passed at the first call site. This practice is error prone and obsolete.

Your sorting function has quadratic time complexity, which can be very slow for very long strings but words should not be too large so this is not a problem.

It would be better to not modifying the argument strings. You can perform the test with a copy of one of the strings with the same time complexity.

Here is a direct approach:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int check_anagrams(const char word1[], const char word2[]) {
    /*
       This function accepts two strings and returns 1 if they
       are anagrams of one another, ignoring spaces.
       The strings are not modified.
     */
    int i, j, len1, letters1, letters2;

    /* compute the length and number of letters of word1 */
    for (len1 = letters1 = 0; word1[len1] != '\0'; len1++) {
        if (word1[len1] != ' ')
            letters1++;
    }

    /* create a copy of word1 in automatic storage */
    char copy[len1];    /* this is an array, not a string */
    for (i = 0; i < len1; i++)
        copy[i] = word1[i];

    for (j = letters2 = 0; word2[j] != '\0'; j++) {
        char temp = word2[j];
        if (temp != ' ') {
            letters2++;
            for (i = 0; i < len1; i++) {
                if (copy[i] == temp) {
                    copy[i] = '\0';
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (i == len1) {
                /* letter was not found */
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    if (letters1 != letters2)
        return 0;
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    const char *s1 = " listen";
    const char *s2 = "silent   ";
    if (argc >= 3) {
        s1 = argv[1];
        s2 = argv[2];
    }
    int result = check_anagrams(s1, s2);
    if (result == 0) {
        printf("\"%s\" and \"%s\" are not anagrams\n", s1, s2);
    } else {
        printf("\"%s\" and \"%s\" are anagrams\n", s1, s2);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: thank you for the detailed response. How can it be that I am modifying memory that belongs to the next array (assuming I’m not making an off-by-one error)? Both arrays consist of 100 elements, and at no point do I go to an out of bounds index (again, barring an off-by-one error). This is an assignment, assuming short inputs, and though I appreciate how inefficient my sort is, all I need is for it to work. I’m not worried about the algorithm taking 4 ms more than it could. Same for functions being defined after the call from main; does it really matter from the compiler’s perspective?

Comment: I didn't implement all the fixes you suggested, but I did seem to solve my particular problem after writing a function to give the length of the input words and not iterating beyond that in the functions that followed. Maybe my understanding is flawed here about the behaviour of C, but I wonder why that mattered at all, since as far as I know, each array is allocated 100 slots worth of memory, so even if I made changes to empty slots at indices <100, why would that affect another memory location? Just curious.

Comment: @P.Gillich: I'm afraid your understanding is flawed: where did you hear that each array is allocated 100 elements? It is not the case at all. Arrays can be allocated with any size, accessing elements of a C string beyond the null terminated must be avoided as it has undefined behavior. For example a C string allocated with `malloc()` may have just the necessary slots and cause a segmentation fault when accessing elements at invalid indices.

Comment: what I mean is that if I declare an array of size 100, doesn’t that mean somewhere a chunk of memory is reserved with enough space to store up to 100 elements? So even if I make changes to indices beyond the one storing the last character in the array, as long as I don’t attempt to change an index which is out of the bounds of the array, why should this affect a different array?

Comment: @P.Gillich: Declaring the array size in a function argument has no effect at all. The function just receives a pointer to the first element of the array passed by the caller. The array size is what it is at the calling spot. Accessing elements beyond the end of the array has undefined behavior, changing them even more so, with a possible side effect such as modifying another array, or anything worse.

Answer (score 1):

You're making a logic error in your helper function. You're starting the copying from `word[j]` instead of at the start of the second word, so you are going to strip as many leading characters as leading spaces, like you see in the output.

Note that `j=i` and `i` counts the number of leading spaces from the outer loop.

By the way you should only have two loops. Put the `while` condition inside the first `for` loop like this: `for (int i = 0; i<100 && word[i]==' '; i++)`.

To fix your logic error, you need to use another iterator `k` initialized to zero in the innermost loop, and use `word[k] = word[j+1]`. I think that'll work.

Comment: I don't understand, shouldn't i and j be reset in different calls to the function? Doesn't i run from 0 to 99, and every time word[i] is a blank space, we enter the second loop?

Comment: @P.Gillich I'm not talking about separate calls to the function, I'm talking about a single call. And no, that is not how loops work. For `i=0`, you iterate through `0 <= j < 100`. So on through to `i=99`.

Comment: @P.Gillich I might have time to look at the rest of your code later. Good luck.

Comment: So then why does it work perfectly in the first call? I don't understand, I see the desired output if I call the function once, but shenanigans on only the second one.

Comment: @P.Gillich Coincidence, probably. Happens all the time. Try some more cases.

Comment: Alright, I'll give that a try in the morning. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but ultimately the logic error seemed to be that I was not being careful about the length of the char array fed to the function. I don't think as stated what you are saying is correct; I am only feeding the function one char array at a time, and each time I call the function, the indices i and j are reset, so in particular it shouldn't matter that I don't initialize the inner loop's index to zero, in fact it has to be initialized to whatever i is at the time.

Comment: @P.Gillich You misunderstood what I wrote, I don't know what else to say. I was proposing you use another variable entirely. I'm glad you sorted out your issue.

Answer (score 1):

You have problem with buffer overflow on argv[1] and argv[2] in case of argv[1] buffer length is less than 100. So I think you should use for loop with strlen(word) that is enough. When you use static length with 100 in for loop, sometime the word will get the data from another memory location and make your program in a undefined behavior. And other functions have the same issue as well. I mean the **sortWords** and **compare** functions.

Here is my modification in your noSpaces function, it should work.

```
void noSpaces(char word [100]){
    /*
    This is a function to get rid of spaces in a word
    It does this by scanning for a space and shifting the
    array elements at indices > where the space is
    down by 1 as long as there is still a space
    there.
    */
    for(int i =0; i<strlen(word)-1; i++){
        while(word[i]==' '){
            for(int j = i ; j<strlen(word); j++){
                word[j] = word [j+1];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to remove spaces and sort, which is O(N lg N) running time.  You can do an O(N) operation by just building up an array that represents the count of each letter in a word. And just ignore spaces while doing this.

```
// Iterate over each character in the string
// For each char in string, increment the count of that character
// in the lettercount array.
// Return the number of unfiltered letters that were counted
int fillLetterCountTable(const char* string, int* lettercount)
{
    int len = strlen(string);
    int valid = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
       unsigned char index = (unsigned char)(string1[i]);
       if (index ==  ' ')  // ignore spaces
       {
           continue;
       }
       counts[index] += 1;
       valid++;
    }

    return valid;
}

// compare if two strings are anagrams of each other
// return true if string1 and string2 are anagrams, false otherwise
bool compare(const char* string1, const char* string2)
{
    int lettercount1[256] = {0};
    int lettercount2[256] = {0};

    int valid1 = fillLetterCountTable(string1, lettercount1);
    int valid2 = fillLetterCountTable(string2, lettercount2);

    if (valid1 != valid2)
        return false;

    // memcmp(lettercount1, lettercount2, sizeof(lettercount1));
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        if (counts1[i] != counts2[i])
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: FYI: This doesn't work with Unicode text, so it's basically unusable in real applications

Comment: OP is clearly using char type.  I see this solution as fair game.  For 16-bit Unicode (ala Windows), just switch from char to  wchar_t and 256 to 65536).  For 32-bit Unicode (ala Mac), you would be correct - a better hash table approach is needed to not blow the stack.  The approach for that would be to have a sorted hash table algorithm that could be used as a "set" and a way to compare two sets for equality.  In C++, you'd just use `std::set<wchar_t>` and be done with it.

Comment: In the more general case, I think it's mostly a question about his current implementation, and the matter at hand is C and not anagram testing. Although there is value in providing a good solution!

Comment: @Alexander Sorting chars within words wouldn't work for Unicode text either.  Anagrams in general might not be well defined for Unicode anyway.

Comment: @selbie while I do like this solution and it had crossed my mind, I thought it would be more instructive to do it the way I did it. I did end up getting it to work, btw. Thanks!

Comment: @jamesdlin Yeah, there's several possible interpretations of "anagram" for Unicode, but probably the one that would make the most sense is having the same count of every extended grapheme cluster, which is what the user ultimately sees as a "character"